# canvas like framebuffer work on chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, canvas

I try to use a canvas like framebuffer, in chrome work ok but in firefox not.
Any expert in firefox can see the code?

in
https://github.com/r3www/r3/blob/master/compiler.js
lines 445..

```
function r3init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d',{alpha:false,preserveDrawingBuffer:true});
    imageData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    buf8=new Uint8ClampedArray(memdata,0,imageData.data.length);

    meminidata=imageData.data.length;// dinamic???
    }

function redraw() { 
    imageData.data.set(buf8);ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0); 
    }
```

r3init set the canvas and redraw copy the memory of framebuffer to canvas.

for try go to 
https://rawgit.com/r3www/r3/master/index.html

and click run.

Thank's

Comment: There is no `function r3init` on that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are relying on a [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=673416&can=1&q=alpha%20false%20putImagedata&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified), which doesn't respect your `alpha: false` CanvasRenderingContext2DSetting, when you put a transparent ImageData.

When you do `ctx.putImageData(ImageData, x, y)` to such a context, the alpha channel should be ignored by the algorithm, and always fully opaque => 255.

[From specs' note](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#concept-canvas-alpha):

> Thus, the bitmap of such a context starts off as opaque black instead of transparent black; clearRect() always results in opaque black pixels, every fourth byte from getImageData() is always 255, the putImageData() method effectively ignores every fourth byte in its input, and so on.

So, I didn't dig exactly what you do to this data, but it seems that you assume the alpha channel is initially 0, while it actually shouldn't be.

A simple fix, is to initialize your context with the default alpha set.
<sub>Also note that preserveDrawingBuffer is a webgl setting, there is no drawing buffer in 2D context.</sub>

```
// alpha for everyone
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

---

Simple test for currently broken Chrome (at least v69.0.3497)

```js
const alpha = document.createElement('canvas')
  .getContext('2d');
const opaque = document.createElement('canvas')
  .getContext('2d', {
    alpha: false
  });
// a transparent ImageData
const transp = alpha.createImageData(300, 150);
// alpha channel should be ignored
opaque.putImageData(transp,0,0);

const opaque_c = opaque
  .getImageData(0,0,4,4)
  .data[3];
const alpha_c = alpha
  .getImageData(0,0,4,4)
  .data[3]

console.log('opaque', opaque_c); // should be 255
console.log('alpha', alpha_c); // should be 0
```

Comment: ok, I resolve the situatio adding $ff always but I leave the flags because Not need transparency and some gain in speed is posible.

Comment: If you are only dealing woth imagedata, disabling imagedata might actually be counter productive. And if I read your project right, you're not running at 60fps anyway.